# Single Binomial Coefficient Sum in Two Free Variables

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I am looking to calculate

$$\sum^{n}_{j = 0}{{a + j}\choose{b}}$$

where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. I realize that if $b = a$ then this is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773190/show-large-sum-limits-j-0r-binomjk-1k-1-binomrkk?rq=1) with a different labeling of variables, but in my case $a$ and $b$ are different.

Among the things I have tried that did not work were the Snake Oil method and applying Hockey-Stick Identities (such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784613/another-hockey-stick-identity)).

Either an analytic or combinatorial proof is fine.

Comment: This leads to a hypergeometric series.

Comment: Is that a difference between two hockey sticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**
Notice that if $a<b=a+c$ then it is the same thing as the case $a=b$ because
$$\sum _{j=0}^n\binom{a+j}{b}=\sum _{j=-c}^{n-c}\binom{a+c+i}{b}=\sum _{j=0}^{n-c}\binom{b+i}{b},$$
can you conclude?
For the case in which $b<a$ then you can write the sum as suggested by **peterwhy** in the comments i.e.,

$$\sum _{j=0}^{a-1}\binom{j}{b}+\sum _{j=0}^{n}\binom{a+j}{b}=\sum _{j=0}^{a+n}\binom{j}{b},$$
can you conclude?

Comment: Hmm ok I am getting ${{a + n + 1}\choose{n + a - b}}$ when $a \leq b$ and ${{a + n + 1}\choose{b + 1}} - {{a}\choose{b + 1}}$ if $a > b$. Even if I made a computational error, all the steps made sense, so thank you!!

Comment: @JoshuaSiktar looks good to me. Check numerically tho. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most direct approach but it does show where hypergeometric functions appear as mentioned by @DrSonnhardGraubner.

---

We write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{a+j}{b}
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{\Gamma(a+1+j)}{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(a-b+1+j)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(a-b+1)}\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{(a+1)_j}{(a-b+1)_j}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(a-b+1)}\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{(a+1)_j(1)_j}{(a-b+1)_j\,j!},
\end{align}
$$
where $(s)_n=\Gamma(s+n)/\Gamma(s)$ is the Pochhammer symbol and $(1)_n=n!$. The result is a partial hypergeometric series, which may be evaluated using [DLMF 16.2.4](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.E4) to give
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{a+j}{b}=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(a-b+1)}\frac{(a+1)_n(1)_n}{(a-b+1)_n\,n!}{_3F_2}\left({-n,1,b-a-n\atop -n,-a-n};1\right).
$$
After some simplification
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{a+j}{b}=\frac{\Gamma(a+1+n)}{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(a-b+1+n)}{_2F_1}\left({1,b-a-n\atop -a-n};1\right).
$$
[Gauss's hypergeometric theorem](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E20) then permits us to write
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{a+j}{b}=\frac{\Gamma(a+1+n)}{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(a-b+1+n)}\frac{\Gamma(-a-n)\Gamma(-1-b)}{\Gamma(-a-n-1)\Gamma(b)},
$$
which can be further reduced to give a sum of two binomial coefficients.